# debugfs command not found

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, filesystems, terminal

When I try to use debugfs on my Macbook pro(10.6.8)  I get

```
-bash: debugfs: command not found
```

Then I try to look at my path

```
echo $PATH
```

I get

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

which seems pretty much everything.

Where is my debugfs command? How can I reinstall it?

Comment: are you sure the debugfs is part of macos? I think you have to install this by yourself and then it will be in your path or in the location where you have chosen to install it.

Comment: I am not sure. Do you know what package should I install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no [debugfs(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) on Mac OS X. [Debugfs(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) is a Linux program used to debug the Linux file system ext2/ext3. If you want to debug a Mac filesystem like HFS+ try [fsck(8)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck.8.html) or use [Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1782?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

If you really want to debug a Linux ext2/ext3 filesystem on a Mac (e.g. an external Linux USB disk) you will have to install ext2/3 first. Since you have /opt/local/bin in your path I suppose you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) installed. In this case you could just install the packet ext2fuse which includes the [debugfs(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) program.

Comment: `debugfs` was not probably available on Os X 2 years ago, but now it is. `e2fstools` are actually available on Os X using `homebrew`.

Comment: To clarify, you can install `e2fstools` using Hombrew but it's part of the package `e2fsprogs`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install `e2fsprogs`, including `debugfs`, using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) on OsX.

```
brew install e2fsprogs
```

You will find `debugfs` in `/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/sbin/debugfs`